# In R after generating a mvrnorm distribution, Y, what does Y[,1] do?

Tags: r, simulation

I have generated a mvrnorm distribution and assigned it to Y. What do Y[,1] and Y[,2] do?

Comment: Assuming `Y` is a matrix, it returns the first or second column (reduced to a one-dimensional vector), e.g. `Y <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = 10, c(0, 0), matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2)); Y[, 1]; Y[, 2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sampling from a multivariate normal distribution. For example in the bivariate case

```
x <- mvrnorm(
    n = 500, 
    mu = c(1, 2), 
    Sigma=matrix(c(4, 2, 2, 3), ncol = 2))
```

`x[, 1]` and `x[, 2]` are two *jointly* normally distributed variables.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x1 = x[, 1], x2 = x[, 2]), aes(x1, x2)) + geom_density_2d()
```

[image]